# Get Rho and Theta from Hough-Transform opencvsharp?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

I have Hough-Transform implemented using Opencvsharp (opencv), and get the lines detected on my image in console application/windows-from-application:

```
lines = edgeImg.HoughLines2(storage, HoughLinesMethod.Probabilistic, 1, Math.PI / 180, 60, 100, 100);

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Total; i++)
{
    CvLineSegmentPoint segP= lines.GetSeqElem<CvLineSegmentPoint>(i).Value;
    double angle = Math.Atan2((segP.P2.Y) - (segP.P1.Y), (segP.P2.X) - (segP.P1.X)) * 180 / Math.PI;

    if (Math.Abs(angle) <= 60)
        continue;

    if (segP.P1.Y > segP.P2.Y + 20 || segP.P1.Y < segP.P2.Y - 20)
        src.Line(segP.P1, segP.P2, CvColor.blue, 2, LineType.AntiAlias, 0);
}
```

I have tried different methods for visualizing the rho-theta space. since "HoughLinesMethod" does all the transformation internally, I have tried to get these values from x,y in the reverse way:

```
double angle = Math.Atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / Math.PI;
double theta = 90 - angle; 
var thetaRad = theta*Math.PI/180;
double rho = (x1 * Math.Cos(thetaRad) + y1 * Math.Sin(thetaRad));
```

- my first question is if I need to get two values for rho/theta, both for x1,y1 and also x2,y2 ; or calculating only one "rho/theta" would be the right intersect? 
  Thanks!
- second, how can I visualize them in the right format? (what I currently see on my outout image is some random white dots at the top left corner of my output)
- third, is it rational to get rho,theta values back in this way or you would suggest to perform the hough transform by myself and reduce the complexity? (I used opencvsharp function for better and efficient performance!)

Comment: Here is the project which includes Hough space visuzlizer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bV3fFCocehE There is the project sources link in video description.

Comment: Note that if you use HoughLinesMethod.Standard, the lines will be given to you in rho/theta format.

Comment: Also, if you get two different rho/theta values for x1,y1 and x2,y2, then your formula for calculating them is wrong. Rho and theta uniquely identify a line, any line segment on that line must have the same rho/theta.

Comment: @HugoRune , the value for rho1 and rho2 are very close to eachother for example 4.0 and 4.00000039 . so if their value would be so close all the time, I can just take one of them into account!